# Changing overloaded operator to return a value instead of a reference

Tags: c++

How do I change the overloaded operator to return a value instead pf a reference?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class IntList 
{ 
private: 
    int list[1]; 
public:
    IntList() {list[0] = 0;}
    int& operator[] (const int index) {return list[index];} 
}; 

int main()
{
    IntList list;

    cout << list[0] << endl;
    list[0] = 1;
    cout << list[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That results in list[0] =1; having a compilation error.

Comment: That is because you are trying to assign to a value

Comment: The code is OK. What do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int operator[] (const int index){}
^^^^^
```

Just remove the `&`. Once you do that you cannot use it for assigning values to the array elements.

> **Difference between returning a reference and a non reference**

As you noticed when `operator []` returns a reference, it can be used on the left hand side of the assignment. This is possible because when you return by reference the return value of `operator []` is an l-value. References are treated as l-values because you can take reference of variables that are stored in memory and have an address.
When `operator []` returns by value the expression `list[0] = 1;` will eventually evaluate<sup>[#]</sup> to something like,

```
1=1;
```

Which is illogical, since `1` is not a l-value, the compiler will generate a diagnostic that the left operand must be a l-value.

<sup>[#] Assuming value of the element at subscript 0 is 1</sup>:

Comment: Thanks, this results in list[0] = 1; breaking. Can you explain why to me? I am new to c++.

Comment: @DavidTunnell: Hope that explains.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by just removing the `&`, so you have
`int operator[] (const int index){}`.
However as you noticed then the problem is that you cannot assign to it without a compilation error because the index operator no longer returns an l-value. So I think you should consider why you want to return a value instead of a reference. It is possible that you want a pattern where the index operator cannot be use to assign to the object, maybe for some sort of read only type object. Your other option is to have a separate function to set it because the index operator can no longer be used to do that

Answer (score 0):

In your code example you are using assignment, which requires that you return a reference.

```
list[0] = 1;
list.operator[](0) = 1;
int& xref = list.operator[](0);
(xref) = 1; // <-- changed the value of list element 0.
```

Given that you want operator[](int index) to return a value, this would translate to:

```
int x = list.operator[](0);
x = 1; <-- you changed x, not list[0].
```

If you want operator[](int index) to return a value but also have list[0] = 1 still work, you're going to need to provide two versions of the operator so that the compiler can determine which behavior you are trying to invoke in a given call:

```
// const member, returns a value.
int operator[] (const int index) const {return list[index];} 

// non const member, which returns a reference to allow n[i] = x;
int& operator[] (const int index) {return list[index];}
```

Note that they must differ by both return type AND member-constness.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class IntList 
{ 
private: 
    int list[1]; 
public:
    IntList() {list[0] = 0;}
    int operator[] (const int index) const { return list[index]; }
    int& operator[] (const int index) {return list[index];} 
}; 

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    IntList list;

    cout << list[0] << endl;
    list[0] = 1;
    int x = list[0];
    cout << list[0] << ", " << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Working demo: http://ideone.com/9UEJND